# Android signed app crashing. Worked before sign

Tags: android, crash, unity-game-engine, signed

as the title says i've recently signed my app but found once i signed my app that it then became unusable. Worked perfectly fine up until i signed it, never had a single issue like this. Then it started killing itself as soon as the unity splashscreen finished displaying(possibly during it i'm not too sure).
Even if i make a debug signed version it does the same thing...killing itself during the Unity splashscreen.
I'm very in-experienced with logcat but these were the only errors to be found within the log in reference/around launching my app.

Note: Using Unity Android.

Any help would be appreciated as it's been two days of bashing my head against a desk.
Thanks in advance.

```
11-06 00:57:52.585 E/Unity   (31921): Error joining threads: 3
11-06 00:57:52.585 E/Unity   (31921):  
11-06 00:57:52.585 E/Unity   (31921): (Filename: /Applications/buildAgent/work/842f9557127e852/Runtime/Threads/Thread.cpp Line: 367)
11-06 00:57:52.585 E/Unity   (31921): 
11-06 00:57:52.815 I/DEBUG   (30096): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
11-06 00:57:52.815 I/DEBUG   (30096): Build fingerprint: 'samsung/GT-I9100/GT-I9100:2.3.3/GINGERBREAD/XWKG1:user/release-keys'




11-06 00:57:59.130 E/lights  ( 2698): write_int: path /sys/class/backlight/pwm-backlight/brightness, value 57
11-06 00:57:59.150 E/lights  ( 2698): write_int: path /sys/class/backlight/pwm-backlight/brightness, value 54
11-06 00:57:59.150 E/InputDispatcher( 2698): channel '4083e180 com.BraydenWale.NoFlyZone/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
11-06 00:57:59.150 E/InputDispatcher( 2698): channel '4083e180 com.BraydenWale.NoFlyZone/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
11-06 00:57:59.150 I/ActivityManager( 2698): Process com.BraydenWale.NoFlyZone (pid 31921) has died.
11-06 00:57:59.150 I/WindowManager( 2698): WIN DEATH: Window{40854bf0 SurfaceView paused=false}
11-06 00:57:59.155 D/Zygote  ( 2587): Process 31921 terminated by signal (11)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you use proguard to obfuscates your code? Signed app is obfuscated automatically during the building process but unsigned debug app won't. Some code should not be obfuscated, such as those referenced by native code.

Here is the [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html) to the documentation about progaurd, hope it helps.

Comment: We had the same issue.  Some code was getting trimmed too, I think.

Comment: Thanks for the response but no i havent used proguard, the only things i have on there is a basic Keystore and my LVL key. Tried removing one/both and trying new Keystores and nothing seems to work.

Comment: Turns out the issue was with the current Unity Build(3.4.2.f2) it had a bug that caused all aps to crash on launch but was only locaslised to Unity Android Basic developers.

Solution was to go and manually download the latest version from the website(3.4.2.f3)

Thanks for the help anyways guys!